# What is the sql statement for searching in text using MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I have text sotred in my DB, for example:

"There are 2 books on the table".

Maybe the user wants to search for "books" or the user wants to search in this text for any thing.

What is the best SQL Statement to do that?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Best"? Best performance? Or best what?

Comment: Yes, best performance :)

Comment: For that you would want to look at setting up and using Full Text Search then. This will prebuild an index of the words contained in your content which is speedier than using LIKE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ... WHERE COL LIKE '%books%'
```

For more complicated scenarios you might want to investigate [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: Full text search may also be better for performance since LIKE '%books%' can't use an index.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a 'like' clause if I understand your question. so

```
select * from table where column like '%book%'
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%books%'
```

or look into [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) if you need to do more complicated stuff